# decrement value localstorage

Tags: jquery, local-storage, decrement

why is `localstorage` not doing anything after typing in a value to take out from the current value?

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var decVal = $(".decVal");
   var currentVal = $(".currentVal");

   currentVal.html(localStorage.getItem("dec"));
   
   $(".decValButton").click(function(){
      var newval = currentVal.val();
      newval = currentVal.val() - decVal.val();
      currentVal.val(newval);
      localStorage.setItem("dec", currentVal.html());
      $(decVal).val("");
   });
});
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="currentValBox">
    <input class="currentVal" type="text" value="100" readonly>
  </div>
        
  <div class="decBox">
    <button class="decValButton">-</button>
    <input class="decVal" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

let's say you take out 10 from `.currentVal` by typing 10 in `.decVal`. the `.currentVal` value should be 90 now but instead it goes back to the default value 100 after refreshing when it should've stayed 90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using **html()** use **val()** to set the value,
the problem is you have 100 as default value  look here `<input class="currentVal" type="text" value="100" readonly>`
and when you load the page you are not overriding the default value correctly,
this is how you do it:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var decVal = $(".decVal");
    var currentVal = $(".currentVal");
    /* check if there is a value in localStorage if not use 100 as default */
    localStorage.getItem("dec") ? currentVal.val(localStorage.getItem("dec")) : currentVal.val(100);

    $(".decValButton").click(function(){
       var newval = currentVal.val();
       newval = currentVal.val() - decVal.val();

       currentVal.val(newval);
       localStorage.setItem("dec", newval);
       $(decVal).val("");
    });
 });
```

another problem is in this line `localStorage.setItem("dec", currentVal.html());` you are setting your localstorage variable as an empty string to set it correctly use your newval instead,

`html()` means the html content, for example if you have a `<div>Hello</div>` the **html()** method will give you Hello as result, for input elements its returns nothing which the case in your example

Comment: why is the `.currentVal` empty

Comment: what do you mean is empty?

Comment: .currentVal probably still holds your old saved empty string,clear your localStorage and reload to see the effect

Comment: the default value 100 should be displayed on the `.currentVal` textbox but it's empty. i mean i can just add another textbox that lets you add value instead of taking out. i added a value. i refreshed the page. it works. but when i take out a value and refreshed, it goes back to not working

Comment: i cleared it. it doesn't work

Comment: i edited my solution check it out

Comment: i figured something out. it's working now but thank you for the follow up solution though. i appreciate it